# Random similar draw sequences

Tags: c#, random

A lot of times when I draw numbers I get 0 and all the time I can see similar draw sequences. Do you know why?

For example:
losowanie(3) -> result 0 some times 1?

Code:

```
 public int losowanie(int w)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
            int s = w - 1;
            return rand.Next(0, s);
        }
```

Code:

[image]

Comment: Instantiate your Random class once and reuse that instance.

Comment: @rene: that's a good suggestion, but I don't think that's the problem. I think OP misunderstood the meaning of the second argument of `Random.Next()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class once and reuse that instance. For example by having a private static field in the class that utilizes the Random sequence. As an aside: I doubt a default seed with Guid.NewGuid() will give better results as to the the parameterless contructor of Random().

```
public class whatever
{
        static Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        // or use new Random(); 

        public int losowanie(int w)
        {
            int s = w - 1;
            return rand.Next(0, s);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can make that `rand` a static field.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this applies, given that OP is seeding the `Random` via a `Guid` rather than just based on the system time.

Comment: @rer Huh, fair enough. I'll admit I only had a quick Google to check whether `NewGuid` might return duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is correct - `losowanie(3)` calls `rand.Next(0, 2)` so only two values can be returned - either `0` or `1`.

You may misunderstand the meaning of `Random.Next(minValue, maxValue)` parameters - check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) for details.

Comment: Actually the second argument is the exclusive upper-bound, so just 0 and 1 can be returned...

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper: have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)

Comment: @digEmAll I check this at the beginning

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper: it clearly states *"maxValue: **The exclusive upper bound** of the random number returned"* ...

Comment: In this example is \n20 random integers from 1000 to 10000: - > I have to add one number more as MaxValue? Similar as here rnd.Next(1000, 10001)

Comment: @Rafael: yes I you need to add +1. So, for example to get numbers in `[0-3]` range , you need to call `rand.Next(0, 4)` ...